# interfacing cuSolver with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue, cusolver

I like to use cuSolver code for Eigen value decomposition of complex matrix in Matlab.

I am using MATLAB CUDA kernel and it seems that its not possible to interface cuSolver with MATLAB as the cuSolver contains the code for host as well as for device (as mentioned here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/#syevd-example1)
while MATLAB CUDA kernel works only for the kernel function..
Please comment.

Any other idea to compute Eigenvalue decomposition of large no of matrices containing complex data in parallel on GPU by using Matlab environment?

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly need to use the MEX interface. This allows you to take in `gpuArray` data, and call kernels and other CUDA library functions.

See the doc: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-mex-functions-containing-cuda-code.html for more.